# Randomly populate R dataframe with integers between

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I would like to create an R dataframe with random integers WITHOUT repetition.

I have come up with this approach which works:

```
rank_random<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 13, ncol = 30)
for (colIdx in seq(1:30) {
rank_random[colIdx,] <-sample(1:ncol(subset(exc_ret, select=-c(Date))), 30, 
replace=F) 
}
```

Comment: We cannot see any information about `exc_ret` or `Date`. It would be good practice on your part to start a fresh R session and try to run your code. You would then get an error message when names are missing in the code you have in your question. (and it would have spotted the missing paren in the first line as well. You should also be aware that dataframes made from matrix objects may behave somewhat differently

Comment: Whoop,ssorry you are right about that. changed names and copied without checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean without repetition on each row. If you meant something else, please clarify.

For your example:

```
N= ncol(subset(exc_ret, select=-c(Date)))
num.rows = 30
t(sapply( seq(num.rows), 
          FUN=function(x){sample(1:N, num.rows, replace=F)} ))
```

To test it for a simpler case

```
N= 5
num.rows = 5
t(sapply( seq(num.rows), 
          FUN=function(x){sample(1:N, num.rows, replace=F)} ))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    4    5    1    3
# [2,]    2    5    1    3    4
# [3,]    5    1    4    3    2
# [4,]    3    4    5    2    1
# [5,]    3    2    5    1    4
```

Comment: You can actually use `replicate`, (wrapper to `sapply`): `t(replicate(num.rows, sample(1:N, num.rows, replace=F)))`